# MS Outlook: Delete mail when manually marked as junk

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, email-filter

When email fails the junk filter and shows up in the inbox, if one marks it as junk, it still goes into the junk folder. It would be nice if that action would cause the message to actually get deleted, because it has already been reviewed. Is there a setting to do that? Message Rules seem to only be for filtering mail when it comes in, not for actions done by the user (marking as spam).

I personally don't use Outlook but am trying to help a non-techy friend with this. I use Thunderbird, where there is an actual setting, "*When I mark messages as junk: Delete them*". Is there a way to do something similar in Outlook?

**EDIT:** In the comments, TiO suggested that there might be something in the Junk E-Mail Options that would help, but I can't seem to find the options at all. The Outlook version is 2011 for Mac (which I did say in my first comment but TiO must have overlooked it). It's actually the Japanese language version, but that shouldn't matter (forgive me if I don't translate something exactly like the English version). TiO gave instructions for 2016, 2010, and 2007, and I had my friend try them all:

- Right-clicking a message and selecting Junk offers only two choices: "Mark as Junk" and "Block Sender" - there is no "Junk E-mail Options" choice.
- Home tab, "Junk" pulldown offers only "Mark as Junk", "Block Sender", and "Protection from Junk E-Mail" (or something similar - that one doesn't make sense to me).
- There is no Options choice on the Tools menu. We looked at the Outlook Preferences (sorry, I called them "environment settings" in the screenshot composite, but I've since found the actual English term), but didn't see anything applicable.

Here is a composite of three screenshots (taken through Skype screen share - sorry for the bad image quality) with some English translation:

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: If you go into the Junk E-Mail options, (This can be found by right clicking on an email, go to the Junk option where upon further options open up, then choose Junk E-mail options) you can choose permanently delete junk email option instead of moving, maybe this will help?

Comment: @TiO: In my friend's Outlook (2011 Mac), right-clicking a message and selecting Junk offers only two choices: "Mark as Junk" and "Block Sender" - there is no "Junk E-mail Options" choice. Are we doing it wrong?

Comment: sorry in outlook 2016 you can do it my way, what version of outlook are you using?  outlook 2010 you can find junk email options under the home tab, look for "Junk" where there should be an arrow by the side that should give you the option to enter junk e-mail options?

Comment: and in outlook 2007 you can access the junk email options by going through: Tools > Options >  click Junk Email on the preferences tab to display the junk e-mail options.

Comment: @TiO: I have editing my question with more info in response to trying everything you suggested. I did give the version, but you must have missed it: 2011 Mac. I use Thunderbird on Windows and don't live near my friend, so I can't test anything personally - we are using Skype to communicate.

Comment: Okay, I have taken a look at the Mac version of Outlook 2011, the Junk E-Mail Protection is the closest thing I can find to the windows Junk E-mail options however the options in there don't match entirely with the windows version and only allows auto delete of junk mail via number of days it is there. this number could be set to 1 to delete after 1 day, maybe 0 will instantly delete but would need testing. Other than that my knowledge on Macs is limited as it is my Fiancee who is the Mac user in the family.

Comment: @TiO: Thanks. But I don't want mail in the Junk folder to be automatically deleted - that folder contains mail that needs to be checked by a human for false positives. I'm talking about mail in the inbox that is manually flagged - I don't want it to go in the Junk folder at all, because it doesn't need to be checked a second time. This seems like it should be an obvious thing to want, but I guess I'm just too used to it from Thunderbird.